# How can i rename vuetify data-table group label?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatables, vuetify.js, grouping

I want to change group label of  vuetify data-table. For earlier versions of Vuetify below the code was working fine but now it doesn't work.

```
<va-data-table-server
  :items-per-page="50"
  :group-by="groupBy"
  row-create
  row-clone
  row-edit
  disable-edit
  disable-show
  disable-clone
  disable-create-redirect
>
  <template v-slot:column.data-table-group>
  </template>
</va-data-table-server>
```

[image: How can i rename vuetify data-table group label]

Here is demo link.

[https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNq9lt9vmzAQx](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a header declaration with the key `data-table-group` to your headers array:

```
data() {
  return {
    headers: [
      { title: 'My renamed group title', key: 'data-table-group' },
      ...
```

This also allows you to move the group column in the table.

[playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Answer (score 2):

Use [header](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/#header-slot) slot

> You can use the dynamic slots `header.<key>` to customize only certain columns. `<key>` corresponds to the key property in the items found in the headers prop.

The key for the "Group" header is `data-table-group` (found by first using the `headers` slot and printing all column data to the UI: [seen here](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)), so the actual slot you need to use is `header.data-table-group`

```html
<template v-slot:header.data-table-group>
  <div>custom</div>
</template>
```

[Vuetify Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)